# Unable to build Dockerfile Error: Unable to access jarfile /dev/docker-files/billing/wlp-extended-8.5.5.9.jar

Tags: jar, docker, dockerfile

here's the directory of my ubuntu.

/../../../

BillingMicroservice.war
db-derby-10.11.1.1-bin.tar.gz
Dockerfile
wlp-extended-8.5.5.9.jar
wlp-runtime-8.5.5.9.jar

and here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu

ADD wlp-extended-8.5.5.9.jar /dev/root/
ADD wlp-runtime-8.5.5.9.jar /dev/root/
ADD BillingMicroservice.war /dev/root/
ADD db-derby-10.11.1.1-bin.tar.gz /dev/root/

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y default-jre
RUN java -jar /dev/docker-files/billing/wlp-runtime-8.5.5.9.jar --acceptLicense /dev/docker-files/billing/
RUN java -jar /dev/docker-files/billing/wlp-extended-8.5.5.9.jar --acceptLicense /dev/docker-files/billing/

EXPOSE 9080
```

when i try to execute the following command in my ubuntu:
**docker build -t xxxxxx/billing .** and it will log the error

**Error: Unable to access jarfile /dev/docker-files/billing/wlp-extended-8.5.5.9.jar**

please help me with this, thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RUN` instruction is running *inside* the container, and according to your Dockerfile;

```
ADD wlp-extended-8.5.5.9.jar /dev/root/
```

You added that file inside `/dev/root/` inside your image. I think those two `RUN` instructions should be:

```
RUN java -jar /dev/root/wlp-runtime-8.5.5.9.jar --acceptLicense /dev/root/
RUN java -jar /dev/root/wlp-extended-8.5.5.9.jar --acceptLicense /dev/root/
```

Comment: hello @theJeztah, i already change the RUN java -jar /dev/docker-files/billing/wlp-runtime-8.5.5.9.jar --acceptLicense /dev/docker-files/billing/ to correct one the one that you comment. which is RUN java -jar /dev/root/wlp-runtime-8.5.5.9.jar --acceptLicense /dev/root/ but still got the same error

Comment: Just realized you're using `ADD`, which also automatically uncompresses compressed files; I suspect it's extracting the files from the `.jar`. Can you change your `ADD` lines to `COPY` instead?